# Derivative of volume with respect to surface area? $\frac{\partial V}{\partial A } = \left( 1/R_1 + 1/R_2 \right)^{-1}$

Tags: differential-geometry

While studying Physical chemistry of interfaces, I encountered the following "theorem" from differential geometry:

> $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial A} =\left( 1/R_1 + 1/R_2 \right)^{-1} $$ where $V,A$ are the body volume and surface area, respectively, and $R_i$ are the principal radii of curvature (implying that the RHS is the inverse of the mean curvature).

Unfortunately, I couldn't find any place mentioning this statement.

> Will someone help me understand why this theorem is true? References might be helpful too. Are there any ways proving this statement without using fancy tools from differential geometry, but rather only multivariable calculus notions?

Thank you

Comment: Context might help. What's the source of the theorem?

Comment: @runway44: thank you! when trying to derive Young-Laplace equation from thermodynamics principles, we obtained $\frac{dF}{dA} = \frac{\partial F}{\partial A}+ \frac{\partial F}{\partial V} \frac{\partial V}{\partial A}$. Then, plugging in $\frac{\partial F}{\partial A}=\gamma$ and $\frac{\partial V}{\partial A} =(1/R_1^2+1/R_2^2)^{−1} $ yields Young-Laplace theorem (F is Helmholtz free energy).

Comment: see page 42 (chapter 3 , section on "equilibrium conditions") in Butt, H. J., Graf, K., & Kappl, M. (2013). Physics and chemistry of interfaces. John Wiley & Sons.

Comment: Are you certain that the radii should be squared? 

The way you have it gives $\frac{\partial V}{\partial A}$ having dimensions of area instead of length. The formula $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial A} =\left( 1/R_1 + 1/R_2 \right)^{-1}$$ 
has the correct dimensions, and also gives the correct answer for a sphere of radius $r$ with $R_1 = R_2=r$

Comment: While this makes sense for a sphere, I don't understand any plausible interpretation. The radii of curvature vary from point to point, but $V$ and $A$ are global. (P.S. I am a differential geometer.) What is the context in the physical chemistry setting?

Comment: @WW1 - you are right, fixed it.
TedShifrin - I added the context in my comment above, together with the source
Thank you

Comment: You should probably ask on a physics or chemistry stackexchange; they might know the appropriate assumptions to make about the volume and surface shapes to make the theorem actually mean something. (You can't prove a theorem if it doesn't mean anything!)

Comment: Thank you!!!! I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(For anyone trying to find the book, the actual title is *Physics and Chemistry of Interfaces*.)

The equation appears to refer to the swept volume and area of a differential element (figure from Dehoff, *Thermodynamics in Materials Science*):

[image]

Assume that the element is created by rotating through infinitesimal arcs $d\phi_1$ and $d\phi_2$ with respective radii of curvature $R_1$ and $R_2$. The swept volume is thus
$$\delta V=R_1R_2\,\delta n\,d\phi_1\,d\phi_2.$$
The change in area when sweeping to the new radii of curvature $R_1+\delta n$ and $R_2+\delta n$ is
\begin{align}\delta A&=(R_1+\delta n)d\phi_1(R_2+\delta n)d\phi_2-(R_1\,d\phi_1)(R_2\,\phi_2).\\
&\approx[R_1R_2+(R_1+R_2)\delta n]\,d\phi_1\,d\phi_2-R_1R_2d\phi_1d\phi_2\\
&=(R_1+R_2)\delta n\,d\phi_1\,d\phi_2.\end{align}

Thus, $$\frac{dV}{dA}=\frac{R_1R_2}{R_1+R_2}=\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\right)^{-1}.$$ Make sense?

Comment: The point missing in the original question is the meaning of $V$ and $A$: They are localized ("infinitesimal quantities," as it were) at a fixed point. I complained loudly that they looked like global quantities.

Comment: Thank you @Chemomechanics! Ted - I apologize, I didn't understand this point too.